# Setting Private Registry in Yarn Doesn't work

Tags: azure-pipelines, yarnpkg

When running yarn workspace install, and it tries to download the dependencies from Azure Artifacts, I keep getting errors that it cannot find them on the "npm" registry

Here are the following steps I am taking in my azure pipeline:

1. Delete the node_modules folder
2. Setup my `.npmrc`

   Set-Content -Path .npmrc -Value "registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{my-org}/_packaging/{my-feed}/npm/registry/
   always-auth=true
   //pkgs.dev.azure.com/{my-org}/_packaging/{my-feed}/npm/registry/:username=helloUser
   //pkgs.dev.azure.com/{my-org}/_packaging/{my-feed}/npm/registry/:_password=$(System.AccessToken)
   //pkgs.dev.azure.com/{my-org}/_packaging/{my-feed}/npm/registry/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value"
3. Install Nativescript globally `yarn global add nativescript`
4. Configure Yarn

   echo "Clean the cache"
   yarn cache clean

   echo "Removing yarn.lock"
   rm yarn.lock

   echo "Removing scio-web"
   rm -rf scio-web

   echo "Set config"
   yarn config delete registry
   yarn config set registry "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{my-org}/_packaging/{my-feed}/npm/registry/"
   yarn config set always-auth true
   yarn config set username helloUser
   yarn config set _password $(System.AccessToken)
   yarn config set email "my.email@org.ca"
   yarn config list

   echo "install workspace"
   yarn workspace myapp-app install --verbose --registry [https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{my-org}/_packaging/{my-feed}/npm/registry](https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/%7Bmy-org%7D/_packaging/%7Bmy-feed%7D/npm/registry)

When yarn workspace runs, I get the following output:

```
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
verbose 0.286440156 Performing "GET" request to "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{my-org}/_packaging/{my-feed}/npm/registry/rimraf".
verbose 0.344506958 Request "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{my-org}/_packaging/{my-feed}/npm/registry/rimraf" finished with status code 401.
verbose 0.358039945 Error: Couldn't find package "rimraf" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/14.18.1/x64/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/14.18.1/x64/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/14.18.1/x64/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:50862:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/14.18.1/x64/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:310:30)
    at /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/14.18.1/x64/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:321:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
error Couldn't find package "rimraf" on the "npm" registry.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

NPM feeds built by Azure with the default settings will only contain the local repository's packages.  If you want publicly available package sas well, you need to set https://registry.npmjs.org as an upstream source.  Details: [Enable upstream sources in an existing feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources#enable-upstream-sources-in-an-existing-feed)